# Are there constituencies for Russia to destroy and annex Israel?

Tags: russian-federation, israel, territory

Recently, The grand mufti of Russia (the topmost Muslim cleric) has suggested to Putin of Russia **to annex Israel and Mecca**:

> *I suggested to Vladimir Putin to deal with **Israel** as the **Crimea**. Suppose that **Mecca** will be Russian, it is the will of Allah to live together in peace, love and harmony* — [IBTimes](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/russia-grand-mufti-calls-vladimir-putin-annex-israel-mecca-it-will-allah-1530436) quoting [Yod News](http://yodnews.ru/news/2015/11/25/mufty).

Presidential spokesman Peskov has obviously attempted to turn it to a joke. However, there are several considerations suggesting that Russians can have plans towards Israel and Saudi Arabia:

The grand mufti of Russia is a respected politician figure. He can't afford random bareword statements, since everything he speaks is backed by the opinion of a large Muslim community ([14%, or 20 million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_in_Russia)) on the territory of today's Russia.

There were multiple occasions when high-ranked Russian officials made some unbelievable claims that turned true after a while:

- «Do not you dare shelling Baghdad! Let us better [smash] **Tbilisi**!» 
  — Zhirinovsky, a Vice Chairman of the State Duma [said in 2002](https://youtu.be/ExfLOwmSD88), six years before [Russia has invaded Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Georgian_War);
- «Complete destruction of **Germany** and arson of **Paris**» — same Zhirinovsky spoke in [February 2015](https://youtu.be/hsLBDF-cqnQ), nine months before [November 2015 Paris attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/November_2015_Paris_attacks) has occurred;
  <sub>Note: video has been compacted; [Full speech, 09:55](https://youtu.be/ZalZYrBoSBo)</sub>
- [**Aleksandr Dugin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleksandr_Dugin), a Russian Neo-Nazi, [a close Putin's advisor and ideologist](http://imrussia.org/en/analysis/world/2041-are-the-kremlin-hardliners-winning) spoke for armed [invasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleksandr_Dugin#Stance_on_Ukraine_and_role_in_Russian_politics) and annexation of Ukraine well ten years before it happened;
- Numerous KGB-sponsored semi-official gangs like [Seliger camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seliger_%28forum%29) claimed for Russia's right to other countries' territories. For example, these nice guys [are wearing T-Shirts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScIZR.jpg) with logo of "Donetsk People's Republic" **back in 2009**, five years before the Russia's invasion to Ukraine.

---

Hence, the question: **Are there any constituencies for the Russia's claims on Israeli territory?**

Comment: Russian Orthodox Church would definitely love to annex the area, for obvious reasons. Not sure they ever officially blabbed that.

Comment: You can find a constituency for any crazy agenda in any arbitrary country, including e.g. for making a new Moon made out of green cheese in Liechtenstein.

Comment: @CountIblis I absolutely agree, but again, we are not talking about a drunken man shouting (semi-)political slogans in a beer bar. They are reputable, high-ranked officials, probably Top-100 politicians in their country. Does it make sense?

Comment: It's not unheard of to hear top-100 politicians making claims for green cheese moons.

Comment: Your four quotes have nothing at all to do with Israel. Quotes 1, 3 & 4 only point that Russian fixation with some ex-SU territories is nothing new (and we already knew). Quote 2 is even less relevant, unless you suggest a Russian link to the bombings (chose any important city in the world, **sooner or later** a terrorist attack or major catastrophe will fail... the trick is ignoring all the failed predictions). For quote 4, I do not think "semi-official gangs" (whatever they are) qualify for "top-100 politicians".

Comment: To put my previous comment in perspective, George H.W. Bush made lots of declarations about the need to invade Iraq, and he finally did invade Iraq. But that does not mean that he followed to the letter **all of his** declarations.

Comment: I understand the question, but you cannot make the logic leap that because **a picked set** of declarations were later fulfilled, then **all of the declarations** will be fulfilled (or even that they will try to fulfil them). See my comment about GHW Bush if you did not get that. Add to that, none of the quotes is from the Mufti, and that the second quote is completely irrelevant unless you suggest a direct link (do you?) between Zhirinovsky quote and the Paris bombings. And yes you want to make the Russians look like scarier, but things like that only make the question dumber.

Comment: @SJuan76, *correlation does not imply causation*. Paris bombings were not necessarily caused by the Vice Chairman of the Russian Duma. Did I say otherwise?

Answer (score 5):

If one ever read the whole passage, one should realize that Talgat Tacetdin (i.e. grand mufti) talked mostly about a slightly different thing. But as people only read what some "IBTimes" quote, I should make it clear.

He spoke rather pro "panarabian" / "muslim" idea of the grand unite state with *Russia* as its heart. He said actually about "**Russia until Mecca**" (including Jerusalem with al-Aqsa, of course).

Having said this, I hope, you realize now what ideas / constituencies are behind this, and why it can't have any consequences in Russia's foreign policy.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. "grand unite state" — so, Russia and ISIS both set the same strategic goal?

Comment: @bytebuster Just trolling or what? This is not Russia's goal, it's an attempt of "loyalist" muslims to emphasize their importance. Besides, "Grand Khalifate" is not just IS's idea, you may find some variant of it virtually in any islamic state. Think of Saudi Arabia, former United Arab Republic etc.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how "Grand Khalifate" of "Russia until Mecca" can count as a legal background. The answers to [relevant Q about ISIS](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8983/what-is-isis-fighting-for) explain it in a very similar way.

Comment: @bytebuster Coz it's an old wish to unite again what was divided once. Now there are dozens of countries sharing (almost) same language, religion and culture, which were a one state many years ago. Not a surprise that any powerful regional player may once proclaim itself as "all-world muslim leader", as IS did. But the point is that Russia never dreamt of such a role. So Kremlin tolerates mufti's speeches as long as he keeps up a good work in internal affairs, yet only takes his words as a joke.